# Call another route to get data

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My flask app defines the following route:

```
@app.route('/logs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log_collection():
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
    
        query = db.session.query(LogData)

        return jsonify([log.to_dict() for logs in query.all()])
```

Then I have defined the second route:

```
@app.route('/display_logs')
def logs():
    # Call /logs endpoint to get data
    return render_template('display_logs.html', data = logs)
```

Is there a way in Flask to call /logs endpoint from /display_logs and get all data?

Answer (score 1):

I find this cleaner:

```
def fetch_logs():
    query = db.session.query(LogData)
    return [_log.to_dict() for _log in query.all()]

@app.route('/logs_ajax', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def logs_ajax():
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
        return jsonify(fetch_logs())


@app.route('/logs_view')
def logs_view():
    return render_template('display_logs.html', data = fetch_logs())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call the method `log_collection()` inside `logs()` method

```
@app.route('/display_logs')
def logs():
    logs = log_collection()
    return render_template('display_logs.html', data = logs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can call the log_collection function in a variable under /display_logs endpoint which it will return the data fetched under /logs

@app.route('/logs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log_collection():
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
    
        query = db.session.query(LogData)

        return jsonify([log.to_dict() for logs in query.all()])

@app.route('/display_logs')
def logs():
    fetchLog = log_collection()
    return render_template('display_logs.html', data = fetchLog)
```